# jupyter notebook not working in vs code kernelspec, zmq

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

using jupyter nbotebook with vs code and throws the dll problem
with zqm library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your virtualenv activate

1. pip uninstall pyzmq
2. pip install pyzmq=="22.0.3"
   second point will throw a warning but it is ok